# How do I make jquery submit flush the commands?

Tags: jquery

How do I make jquery submit flush the commands?

This line

```
$("#someDiv").append("pid: "+missing[i]+" guid:"+guid_key+" type: "+all_types[j]);
```

only updates `someDiv` when submit function completes, i.e. at the end of the entire submit function.

```
$("#target").submit(function() {
//Some code missing 

for (var i = 0; i < missing.length; i++) {
    var guid_set_for_program = getGuids($("#vodsco_url").val() + "/getGuids/TitleVI/" + missing[i]);
    //now we call each of those endpoints with the results of these guids
    console.log(guid_set_for_program);
    if (guid_set_for_program != null) {
        for(guid_key of guid_set_for_program.keys()) {

            for (var j = 0; j < all_types.length; j++) {
                console.log(guid_key);
                if(! isSuccess(makeAjaxCall($("#vodsco_url").val() + getUrlBySpecifier(all_types[j], guid_key, "TitleVI"), false))){
                    $("#someDiv").append("pid: "+missing[i]+" guid:"+guid_key+" type: "+all_types[j]);
                    appended_something = true;
                    console.log("FAILURE");
                }
            }

            if(appended_something == false){
                $("#regTitle").append("All vodscope lookups were successes.");
            }
        }
    }
}
missing = [];
return false;
}, 0);
```

This call takes 10 seconds:

```
if(! isSuccess(makeAjaxCall($("#vodsco_url").val() + getUrlBySpecifier(all_types[j], guid_key, "TitleVI"), false))){
```

I'm doing sync calls because they are CORS requests. I don't think the endpoint supports jsonp so I have to do async CORS requests with the special header.

Each request call might take 10 seconds to resolve. So I want the DOM to be updated in between each request.

Comment: What do you mean?  Can you explain the problem and provide working code which actually demonstrates the problem?  Any time you call `append()` it will update the DOM immediately.  What isn't working?

Comment: It only updates somediv in the dom after the submit function completes-- at the end of the entire submit function.

Comment: It's still not really clear what the problem is.  Is there some blocking operation that's taking a long time?  If you just loop through calls to append items to the DOM, that loop should happen near instantaneously.  There would be no perceivable difference between rendering all appends at once vs. each individually.  When you debug this, what's the actual bottleneck in this loop?

Comment: Each request might take 10 seconds to resolve. So I want the dom to be updated in between each request.

Comment: What "request"? The AJAX requests? AJAX is asynchronous and non-blocking. The UI updates would all happen immediately and the multiple AJAX requests would complete at a later time. Unless you're somehow *blocking* on AJAX requests. In which case there's your answer... Don't do that. If you are *forcing* your UI to block on asynchronous operations, then that would answer the question of why your UI is blocking on asynchronous operations. It sounds like whatever happens in your `makeAjaxCall()` function is causing problems.

Comment: This call takes 10 seconds if(! isSuccess(makeAjaxCall($("#vodsco_url").val() + getUrlBySpecifier(all_types[j], guid_key, "TitleVI"), false))){

Comment: I'm doing sync calls because they are CORS requests.

Comment: I don't think the endpoint supports jsonp so I have to do async CORS requests with the special header.

Comment: But still....  I'm wondering why all of the dom updates happen at the end of the function execution and not immediately.

Comment: I guess if you *must* make a blocking AJAX call (I'm not convinced you do, but whatever) then you'll have to introduce some non-blocking operation as part of this. A loop is blocking, so that's out. Maybe wrap the operation in a `Promise` and loop over that appending the subsequent operations? Or perhaps some kind of recursive callback structure which invokes the next callback with a `setTimeout()` (even just a few milliseconds will suffice).

Comment: How do I do this without blocking? I'm making a cross-origin ajax request. Doesn't it need to be blocking?

Answer (score 0):

*If we assume that your CORS AJAX request needs to be blocking* (and I don't know enough about CORS to stipulate that it does, but if you have a link supporting that I'd love to see it), then you're going to need a non-blocking *control structure* instead.

Currently your control structure is roughly equivalent (simplified) to this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < all_types.length; j++) {
    performLongBlockingOperation();
    quicklyUpdateUI();
}
```

The problem here (again, if we assume the first statement above) is not that the operation itself is blocking, but that that control structure around it (the `for` loop) is *also* blocking.  That is, there's nothing inherent to a `for` loop that would allow the system to do anything else between iterations.

This problem has come up countless times in, say, Windows Forms applications.  The band-aid solution for many years was to call `DoEvents()` (or something of that nature, it's been a while) which explicitly tells the UI to update.  I don't know of an equivalent in JavaScript, probably because the problem is considerably more rare.

However, we may still be able to achieve the same thing.  We just need a *non-blocking* control structure.  And, luckily, since the blocking operation takes a very long time (several seconds each iteration), we have some flexibility in the amount of time we can delay things without being noticed.

Suppose instead of iterating over a `for` loop, we recursively *schedule* these operations to take place.  Each one as a callback from the previous, so the looping order is preserved, but allowing us to introduce some non-blocking time *between* operations.  Perhaps something like this:

```
var j = 0;
performLongBlockingOperationWrapper(j);

function performLongBlockingOperationWrapper(count) {
    if (count >= all_types.length) {
        return;
    }
    performLongBlockingOperation();
    setTimeout(function () {
        performLongBlockingOperationWrapper(count + 1)
    }, 500);
}
```

The idea here is that each "iteration" of the "loop" (which is more of a recursion than a loop now) performs the operation and then *schedules* the next "iteration" for half a second later.  (Or any arbitrary amount of time you'd like to use, really.)

The elements of the loop are still there.  `j` is declared, there's a terminating condition to check if `j` has reached the end and stop executing, and `j` (or `count` inside the function, or whatever you want to call it) is incremented with each "iteration".  All that's really changed is that we've introduced a *delay* in each iteration of the loop.  And not an artificial blocking delay (the equivalent of a `Thread.Sleep()`, if JavaScript even has one), but simply a non-blocking delay before beginning the next operation.

Comment: This seems so complicated for such a simple problem. I just want the UI to update each time I call regTitle.append and not wait until the end of the entire submit block to conclude.

Comment: @ReginaldBop: What's complicated about it?  All this does is call a wrapper function instead of a loop iteration.  The concept is the same.  If you've found another solution, by all means post it.

Comment: Ok, I see. How do people make ajax request to a google api or something like that? I mean does everything have to be cross-origin? It seems stupid... why can't I make a nonblocking ajax get request to google

Comment: @ReginaldBop: I'm not enough of an expert on CORS to really speak to that, and the details behind it (if it's even a correct assertion) sound like it would make a valid Stack Overflow question on its own.